# 403 forbidden error on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an MVC4 Application deployed on my IIS server and the issue that i'm facing is, when i leave my application idle for 20min and perform my login post service call it is returning me 403 forbidden error,but the next subsequent service call succeeds.here is my code

```
LoginController:

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Result.UserName, false);
 return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index", "Home") });

web.config:

<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/login/Login" timeout="20" />
    </authentication>
```

Is there any setting related To IIS that i need to change?
B.T.W The idle timeout settings for my application pool is 20 min..

Regards

Answer (score 1):

IIS7 shuts down the application when it receives no requests for a certain length of time.

There are two ways that you can handle this.

Modify the "Idle Timeout" value within the application pool. By default it will shutdown the application if there are no requests for 20 minutes

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0 you can use the new Auto-Start behavior to keep the app "Always Running" you can see this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx  post for examples on how to configure it.

Comment: i have hosted my application on IIS6 and set the application pool idle timeout to 0..but still its not working
i have this piece of code in my web.config..is this causing 403 error?
 <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/login/Login" timeout="20" />
        </authentication>

Comment: yes. Please try changing that time to 2 mins or less to reproduce your issue.

Comment: inspite of changing the timeout to 2 sec..i was able to login

Comment: The timeout is in minutes.